# What's the opposite of 414 HTTP status code : Too short

Tags: javascript, http, http-status-codes

I am searching for the suitable HTTP status code when the request contains a String parameter that its size should be at least 20 characters.

I want to return the suitable HTTP status code that reflects `Too short ..`.However,  I got only `Too long...` which is `414` HTTP status code .

I am aware that `422` can be enough since it means `No valid`. However, I feel it is general .

```
   const validateContent = (req, res, next) => {
     const  {content} = req.body;
      if (content && content.length < 20 ) {
        res.status(422).send('Too short');
      } else {
        next()
      }
    }
```

This is my middleware as I mentioned before.

Comment: 414 is "URI too long" - i.e. the server can't actually process it.  The semantics aren't a generic "too long".

Comment: 414 relates to the URL rather than to request body, is it a good idea to repurpose?

Comment: I would recommend 400 since the request is technically malformed.

Answer (score 0):

I think 400 (Bad request) would be apt for you scenario. Because basically to want to say that there was something wrong with the request.